# web.js and native.js platform targets not working in React Native Web file names

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`*.web.js` and `*.native.js` platform targeting isn't working in React Native Web file naming. This path is correct `import { Foo } from './Foo/Foo';` however it returns to following error:

```
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

There's currently very little documentation on this, so I'll map it all out. This works for me only when the path goes back through the `src` directory, i.e. `../components/Foo/Foo`, rather than using a more direct path `./Foo/Foo` when importing from other components. Here's the working files:

***src/components/Foo/Foo.native.js***:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class FooNative extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View></View>
    )
  }
}

export { FooNative as Foo };
```

***src/components/Foo/Foo.web.js***:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class FooWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View></View>
    )
  }
}

export { FooWeb as Foo };
```

***src/components/Bar.js***:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Foo } from '../components/Foo/Foo';

export default class Bar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Foo></Foo>
    )
  }
}
```